# localDB Windows XP Embedded

Tags: c#, sql, windows, embedded, localdb

I've created an application with visual studio c# and I've used an localDB.

When I start the application in computer with windows XP, 7 or 8 ( after installation of SQL Server 2014 LocalDB Express  from this web site: http://www.microsoft.com/it-it/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) works fine, but I the OS is win XP Embedded isn't impossible to instal localDB and I can't run my application.

can SomeOne  help me?

Comment: i think this is about installing the wrong version maybe? Have you tried installing it on a non-embedded win xp

Comment: the S.O says: "try to update a servicepack with new instalsheald

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your embed win XP isn't ready to run the service AND / OR localDB. First I would update your Win XP asap than try it again.

If this hasn't fixed your issue you might want to use another pc or an embed win 7.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft

> Supported Operating System
>
> Windows 7, Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows
>   Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012,
>   Windows Server 2012 R2

These are the operating systems for SQL Server 2014 Express. So how did you install it on an XP system?

Comment: in my company we still use xp embedded :(

Comment: With xp embedded you can use SQLLite or the Compact SQL Server.

Comment: You can also use Firebird DB :)